# how to give spacing between these images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

i have put 6 images in a rectangle form one kept next to another somewhat like this
[image: my home page]

all the images like car mobile and all. i want to see them with some amount of space between them,because i want to do some hover and other stuff over the images for various categories and for that images needs to look little separated(for better UI).my div section which covers the blue area you see having categories inside them is :

```
<div class="jumbotron">
   <h1>categories</h1>
         <p>
            <img class="book" src="book_main.jpg" alt="book face" style="float:top;width:150px;height:130px" href="">
              <img class="mobiles"src="mobile_main.jpg" alt="mobiles face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" href="">
              <img class="vehicles"src="vehicle_main.jpg" alt="vehicles face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" href=""><br>
              <img class="animals"src="animals_main.jpg" alt="animals face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" href="">
              <img class="jobs"src="jobs_main.jpg" alt="jobs face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" href="">
              <img class="furniture"src="furniture_main.jpg" alt="furniture   face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" href=""><br>
         </p>
  </div>
```

and other style sheet i am using here is bootstrap.min.css(for jumbotron ,available on their link :http://getbootstrap.com/).
how to give spacing ?any ideas?

Comment: `href` for `img` never saw that

Comment: if user clicks on the img i have a new page to load to.. @VitorinoFernandes

Comment: Then you should be wrapping the `<img>` in separate `<a>` tags. Your code is invalid.

Comment: can you elaborate a little @Lee

Comment: If you ever want to link anything in HTML, then you need to surround the element you're using as your link with `<a href="your-source">` and `</a>` tags. This is a standard hyperlink rule, and applies to text and images.

Comment: thanks i will try to follow the same then @Lee

Comment: one more doubt guys..the div=jumbotron is not able to be extended beyond that limit you see in the image.i want it to get little lengthier at bottom .do we have any css property for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS Margin Property simply Does This.

You Can Try This:

```css
img{
    margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
   <h1>categories</h1>
         <p>
            <img class="book" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTyEf.jpg?s=128&g=1" alt="book face" style="float:top;width:150px;height:130px" >
              <img class="mobiles"src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTyEf.jpg?s=128&g=1" alt="mobiles face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" >
              <img class="vehicles"src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTyEf.jpg?s=128&g=1" alt="vehicles face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px"><br>
              <img class="animals"src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTyEf.jpg?s=128&g=1" alt="animals face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" >
              <img class="jobs"src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTyEf.jpg?s=128&g=1" alt="jobs face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" >
              <img class="furniture"src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTyEf.jpg?s=128&g=1" alt="furniture   face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" ><br>
         </p>
  </div>
```

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/ewjkeuso/2/)

Answer (score 1):

A margin to the images to have some space between the images.

```
   div.jumbotron img {
        margin: 5px; /* adjust this based on your need */
    }

    <div class="jumbotron">
       <h1>categories</h1>
             <p>
                <img class="book" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/opQJ0.jpg?s=128&g=1" alt="book face" style="float:top;width:150px;height:130px" >
                  <img class="mobiles"src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/opQJ0.jpg?s=128&g=1" alt="mobiles face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" >
                  <img class="vehicles"src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/opQJ0.jpg?s=128&g=1" alt="vehicles face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" href=""><br>
                  <img class="animals"src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/opQJ0.jpg?s=128&g=1" alt="animals face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" >
                  <img class="jobs"src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/opQJ0.jpg?s=128&g=1" alt="jobs face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" >
                  <img class="furniture"src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/opQJ0.jpg?s=128&g=1" alt="furniture   face" style="float:left;width:150px;height:130px" ><br>
             </p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

***CSS***

```
   div.jumbotron img {
        padding:5px; 
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7d1saq6f/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use margin attribute or padding attribute to give space top, bottom, left, right as you need.

```
.jumbotron img {
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

or

```
.jumbotron img {
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```